# jwplayer not playing in ie8

Tags: javascript, flash, jwplayer

Hi I have been using this embedding code to play jwplayer on my site, at it works fine with chrome,firefox and safari. and would be fine with any html compatible browser, however i would like to make the videos available for people viewing in ie8. is there something I can add to the code to make this possible?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">HD video coming up!</div>
       <script>

        var options = {

               file: "clash.mp4",
               height: 270,
               width: 480,
               modes:
                     [
                        { type: "html5" },
                        { type: "flash", src:"/jwplayer/player.swf" }
                     ],

                        };
          jwplayer("container").setup(options);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should not have any problem with that setup as long as IE8 has Flash Player installed.

Answer (score 0):

That should work fine, do you have a link that we can take a look at?